# Gradle flavors, applicationId and not resolved custom view attributes

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-custom-view, android-productflavors

I have a custom view based on GridLayout:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

...

public class GridLayoutForceSizeCells extends GridLayout
{
}
```

I have defined an xml with custom attributes for this class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="GridLayoutForceSizeCells">
        <attr name="totalImages" format="integer" />
        <attr name="desiredColumnCount" format="integer" />
        <attr name="spacing" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="autoGenerate" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then, I have a layout using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <com.mycompany.myapp.GridLayoutForceSizeCells
        xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mycompany.myapp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/cellsGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        grid:desiredColumnCount="20"
        grid:totalImages="0"
        grid:spacing="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I am encountering is that when I change applicationId through a gradle flavor custom attributes are not resolved. I have read in gradlew help that the application package is the one used for R when it is decoupled using gradlew applicationId entry. So, applicationId should not affect my custom attributes package. But when I set applicationId to anything different from com.mycompany.myapp an error arises claiming that attributes can't be resolved.

Has anybody found a solution to this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Finally fix it using xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to let it resolve the package for me in the layout file instead of the full package name.

Comment: Hi @Notbad , I am still facing this issue. I am getting error Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.example.abcd.flavor1.views.ExpandableAppBarBehavior on adding flavor 1 as a new product flaovr with applicationIdsuffix flavor1. Earlier it was working fine when package was just com.example.abcd.  ,,,, Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong here